# $f'(x) \geq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \iff f \text{ if convex}$: Does this inequality hold?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

[It is well-known that convexity of a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \geq f'(y)$ are equivalent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317196/f-convex-iff-fy-geq-fxy-xfx)

Can we also say that convexity implies $f'(x) \geq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}$ ($\ \forall x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}$) and vice-versa? (Even if not equivalent statements, maybe at least one sided implication holds?)

If $x > y$ and $f$ is increasing, then $f'(x)(x-y) \geq f(x) - f(y)$ certainly holds (as the derivative at $x$ exceeds the derivative at any of the points in $(x,y)$. Since $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ is the derivative of some $z \in (x,y)$ which we can show using the mean value theorem, the inequality holds.)

But is that true without these (above) restrictions (like $x>y$ and $f \uparrow$)?

Comment: The first line requires $y <x$.

Comment: Note:  $f$ convex does not imply $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$.

Comment: @GEdgar We are assuming that $f$ is differentiable over its entire domain. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequalities do not hold for all $x,y, x\neq y$.

If $f$ is assumed to be differentiable then it can be shown that  $f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^{y} f'(t)dt\leq f'(y) (y-x)$ provided $x<y$.

The equality here is a special result for convex functions and the inequality follows from the fact that $f'$ is increasing.

What we have is $f'(y) \geq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\geq f'(x)$ for $x<y$.